# g:form doesn't seem to have a "controller" attribute

Tags: grails, gsp

Recently I began to study Grails, and I noticed that the file `create.groovy`  is generated by a dynamic scaffold. The form tag doesn't have an attribute called `controller`, only `action`.

So my question is, how does the Grails framework discover the controller that should be called?

```
<g:form action="save">
            <fieldset class="form">
                <f:field bean="categoria" property="nome" class="form-control" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails uses *"convention over configuration"* so whenever you use a form without controller, grails will use the default convention.

Since your view is put in a folder named after a controller, grails will assume that the default controller for any view inside that folder is the one that matches with the folder name. Example

BookController is the default   controller for any gsp inside the *grails-app/views/book* folder.

*This convention also applies to things like links.

Comment: Thanks Omar, very instructive! I am studying grails and english you can pass your e-mail or add me in facebook for we talk about? Ony if you do not feel bothered. I live in Brasil, my e-mail is jdanielts1@gmail.com.